# IOT cloud hardware user manual

Tags: aws-iot, nb-iot

Can someone help me to understand the IOT cloud architecture from hardware point of view? I wanted to know how cloud hardware is implemented to make it internet ready i.e. whether it uses Ethernet or any other hardware porting techniques. I tried to browse the internet for this information but unable to fetch anything concrete that only describes about the protocol level information.

I am specifically interested about cloud connected cellular IOT connectivity.

Thanks

Comment: cellular technology does not use ethernet for connectivity